# I want to inhibit the autostart of kwalletd5

Tags: linux, dbus

I'm not able to find a way to disable the automatic start of kwalletd5 on Fedora 24 with XFCE4.

pstree displays:

```
fetchmail

firefox─┬─{BgHangManager}
        ├─{Cache I/O}
        ├─{Cache2 I/O}
        ├─{Cert Verify}
        ├─{Compositor}
        ├─{DNS Resolver #1}
        ├─{DNS Resolver #2}
        ├─3*[{DOM Worker}]
        ├─{DataStorage}
        ├─{GMPThread}
        ├─{Gecko_IOThread}
        ├─{HTML5 Parser}
        ├─{Hang Monitor}
        ├─{IPDL Background}
        ├─{ImageBridgeChil}
        ├─{ImageIO}
        ├─{ImgDecoder #1}
        ├─{ImgDecoder #2}
        ├─6*[{JS Helper}]
        ├─{JS Watchdog}
        ├─{Link Monitor}
        ├─{Proxy R~olution}
        ├─{Socket Thread}
        ├─{SoftwareVsyncTh}
        ├─{Timer}
        ├─{URL Classifier}
        ├─{dconf worker}
        ├─{gdbus}
        ├─{gmain}
        ├─{localStorage DB}
        ├─{mozStorage #1}
        ├─{mozStorage #2}
        ├─{mozStorage #3}
        ├─{mozStorage #4}
        ├─{mozStorage #5}
        ├─{mozStorage #6}
        └─{mozStorage #7}

gpg-agent

sh─┬─ssh-agent
   └─xfce4-session─┬─abrt-applet─┬─{gdbus}
                   │             └─{gmain}
                   ├─korgac─┬─{QDBusConnection}
                   │        ├─3*[{QThread}]
                   │        └─{QXcbEventReader}
                   ├─nm-applet─┬─{dconf worker}
                   │           ├─{gdbus}
                   │           └─{gmain}
                   ├─seapplet
                   ├─xfce-polkit─┬─{gdbus}
                   │             └─{gmain}
                   ├─xfce4-panel─┬─audacious─┬─3*[{audacious}]
                   │             │           ├─{gdbus}
                   │             │           ├─{gmain}
                   │             │           └─{threaded-ml}
                   │             ├─panel-10-power-─┬─{gdbus}
                   │             │                 └─{gmain}
                   │             ├─panel-2-actions─┬─{gdbus}
                   │             │                 └─{gmain}
                   │             ├─panel-6-systray
                   │             ├─{gdbus}
                   │             └─{gmain}
                   ├─xfce4-terminal─┬─bash───pstree
                   │                ├─bash───su───bash
                   │                ├─2*[bash]
                   │                ├─{gdbus}
                   │                └─{gmain}
                   ├─xfdesktop─┬─{gdbus}
                   │           └─{gmain}
                   ├─xfwm4
                   ├─xscreensaver
                   ├─{gdbus}
                   └─{gmain}

pulseaudio─┬─gconf-helper
           ├─{alsa-sink-VT170}
           └─{alsa-source-VT1}

systemd─┬─(sd-pam)
        ├─at-spi-bus-laun─┬─dbus-daemon───{dbus-daemon}
        │                 ├─{dconf worker}
        │                 ├─{gdbus}
        │                 └─{gmain}
        ├─at-spi2-registr─┬─{gdbus}
        │                 └─{gmain}
        ├─dbus-daemon───{dbus-daemon}
        ├─gconfd-2
        ├─gvfs-afc-volume─┬─{gdbus}
        │                 ├─{gmain}
        │                 └─{gvfs-afc-volume}
        ├─gvfs-gphoto2-vo─┬─{gdbus}
        │                 └─{gmain}
        ├─gvfs-udisks2-vo─┬─{gdbus}
        │                 └─{gmain}
        ├─gvfsd─┬─{gdbus}
        │       └─{gmain}
        ├─gvfsd-fuse─┬─{gdbus}
        │            ├─{gmain}
        │            ├─{gvfs-fuse-sub}
        │            └─2*[{gvfsd-fuse}]
        ├─gvfsd-metadata─┬─{gdbus}
        │                └─{gmain}
        ├─gvfsd-trash─┬─{gdbus}
        │             └─{gmain}
        ├─imsettings-daem─┬─{gdbus}
        │                 └─{gmain}
        ├─kded5─┬─{QDBusConnection}
        │       └─{QXcbEventReader}
        ├─kdeinit5───klauncher─┬─{QDBusConnection}
        │                      └─{QXcbEventReader}
        ├─kiod5─┬─{QDBusConnection}
        │       └─{QXcbEventReader}
        ├─kwalletd5─┬─{QDBusConnection}
        │           └─{QXcbEventReader}
        └─xfconfd

thunderbird─┬─{BgHangManager}
            ├─{Cache I/O}
            ├─{Cache2 I/O}
            ├─{Cert Verify}
            ├─{Closing Service}
            ├─{Compositor}
            ├─2*[{DOM Worker}]
            ├─{Gecko_IOThread}
            ├─{HTML5 Parser}
            ├─{Hang Monitor}
            ├─{IPDL Background}
            ├─{ImageBridgeChil}
            ├─{ImageIO}
            ├─{ImgDecoder #1}
            ├─{ImgDecoder #2}
            ├─6*[{JS Helper}]
            ├─{JS Watchdog}
            ├─{Link Monitor}
            ├─{Proxy R~olution}
            ├─{Socket Thread}
            ├─{SoftwareVsyncTh}
            ├─{Timer}
            ├─{URL Classifier}
            ├─{dconf worker}
            ├─{gdbus}
            ├─{gmain}
            ├─{localStorage DB}
            ├─{mozStorage #1}
            ├─{mozStorage #2}
            ├─{mozStorage #3}
            ├─{mozStorage #4}
            ├─{mozStorage #5}
            └─{thunderbird}

xfce4-power-man─┬─{gdbus}
                └─{gmain}

xfsettingsd─┬─{gdbus}
            └─{gmain}
```

And systemctl --user status dbus.service says:

```
    ● dbus.service - D-Bus User Message Bus
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/dbus.service; static; vendor preset: en
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-09-30 08:55:48 CEST; 1h 34min ago
     Docs: man:dbus-daemon(1)
 Main PID: 2174 (dbus-daemon)
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/dbus.service
           ├─2174 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --n
           ├─2188 /usr/libexec/imsettings-daemon
           ├─2205 /usr/lib/xfce4/xfconf/xfconfd
           ├─2866 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
           ├─2886 /usr/bin/kded5
           ├─2900 kdeinit5: Running...       
           ├─2901 /usr/libexec/kf5/klauncher --fd=8
           ├─3117 /usr/bin/kwalletd5
           └─3172 /usr/libexec/kf5/kiod5
```

Any good idea is welcome.

Thanks a lot,
Claude

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
System Settings -> Account Details -> KDE Wallet -> Wallet Preferences
```

then **un**select (= untick) *Enable the KDE Wallet subsystem*.

Comment: Sorry Marius ! Please delete the word  "unfortunately" in my previous note.

Comment: @ClaudeFrantz But does this mean the above works or not?